# groupby and function call in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where i have a column "Name". Name have multiples values like sample1, sample2, sample3. I want to apply a function to all those groups where value in Name column is same.

Output:

```
   Name  Value  Result
0  Name1      2       5
1  Name1      3       5
2  Name2      1      11
3  Name2      4      11
4  Name2      6      11
5  Name3      8      10
6  Name3      2      10
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Pandas `groupby` function? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = # ... load your data

def group_sum(g):
    g["Result"] = g["Value"].sum()
    return g

df_grouped = df.groupby("Name").apply(group_sum)
```

Edit: Alexandre Nixon's answer is better for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: function (x.value))
```

The will work, in x.value you can put your column name